# Cannot directly execute script on docker volume

Tags: docker

Environment:

```
Docker version 18.06.1-ce, build e68fc7a
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
Storage Driver: overlay2

Aforementioned volume: 
        {
            "Type": "volume",
            "Name": "xxx",
            "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/xxx/_data",
            "Destination": "/tmp",
            "Driver": "local",
            "Mode": "",
            "RW": true,
            "Propagation": ""
        },
```

When I'm trying to create script in this directory (trying to replicate issue with yet-another-docker-plugin) : `touch init.sh && chmod +x init.sh && ./init.sh` I get "permission denied" failure.

Flags seems to be set properly by chmod: `-rwxr-xr-x 1 root   root`

Scripts can be launched in any other directory, but not on the volumes.

What is most interesting, launching the script with command `bash init.sh` works!

What might be the reason of such strange behavior and how to fix it?

Comment: I think you don't have the execution permission on init.sh script for the user. Please try `chmod a+x init.sh` adding the `a` before `+x`

Comment: @MarioSantini that's not the issue, the command above works everywhere else, just not in /tmp directory, which apparently is a volume.

Comment: That sounds like, at a mechanical level, the volume might be mounted `noexec`.  Volumes aren’t really intended to hold code, though, and you generally shouldn’t be poking around inside `/var/lib/docker`.

Comment: I mean, the execution permissions on the folder are not relevant as they just allow the user to access the folder. I think the issue is on the file, and you may not have the executable permissions as docker user that run the command on the volume.

Comment: @DavidMaze @MarioSantini - `touch init.sh && chmod +x init.sh && ./init.sh` does not work, but `touch init.sh && chmod +x init.sh && bash  "./init.sh"` does

Comment: @DavidMaze - I'm not poking around /var/lib/docker, I'm executing from inside container in directory /tmp, which is a volume.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was playing around a bit to try and replicate.

This series of commands worked.

```
docker volume create mine
docker run -it -v mine:/tmp ubuntu bash
touch init.sh && chmod +x init.sh && ./init.sh
```

Inspecting the volume got-

```
        {
            "Type": "volume",
            "Name": "mine",
            "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/mine/_data",
            "Destination": "/tmp",
            "Driver": "local",
            "Mode": "z",
            "RW": true,
            "Propagation": ""
        }
```

The difference is the "Mode" which I think is "z" because I am not running selinux.

I tried some different options to duplicate your problem

```
docker run -it --mount type=volume,source=mine,target=/tmp,readonly ubuntu bash -c "cd /tmp && touch init.sh && chmod +x init.sh && ./init.sh"
touch: cannot touch 'init.sh': Read-only file system
```

But I couldn't.
Looking into some links I found this issue, which links to an article
https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/7054
https://lwn.net/Articles/281157/

The article says that bind mounts inherit mount options (such as noexec) from the mount. So... is your docker folder on a mount that is mounted with noexec?

Comment: Aaaand It turns out I am and idiot.
So tempted to remove the question, but it would be bad sportsmanship ;)
I't amazing how fixated one can get on small picture and not see the real problem.

I'm still dumfounded though why bash ./test works.
It might be a good follow up question.

Comment: because you don't need the execution permission to feed a text file as an input to another executable (bash in this case)

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is because the POSIX of `/tmp` does not allow you to execute the script. 
You can verify that by issuing `getfacl init.sh`.

By using `chmod +x init.sh`, you only add the execute permission for all users to the existing permissions.

By using `chmod 755 init.sh`, you set the full permissions for the owner as well as read and execute permission for others.

I believe that should do the trick.